# Transition delay for cursor hover in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm building a JavaFX application. I made a cursor hover effect on a button with CSS. How can I make a delay on it? Tried `-fx-transition-delay:` but it didn't work.

Comment: You can't do this directly in CSS in JavaFX: you need to do it in Java (register a listener with the `hoveredProperty()` of the node, start a `PauseTransition`, and on completion of the `PauseTransition`, if the node is still hovered apply a CSS style class or pseudoclass to the node).

Comment: JavaFX nodes provide a set of properties that can be used from css. Set is mostly unrelated to html+css (there are a couple of similar properties though). In order to use a `-fx-transition-delay` property you'd need to extend `Button` and add this property yourself. Furthermore you'd need to add your own pseudoclass to replace the `:hover` pseudoclass and make sure to modify all relevant styles of the default style.